# Disable spell checking on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, spell-checking

I'm trying to disable spell checking in MacOS's IntelliJ IDEA version 8.1.

How can I disable it?

Comment: This applies to the Win version as well.

Answer (score 436):

Follow :

```
File >> Settings >> Editor >> Inspections >> Proofreading >> Typo
```

`->` **Uncheck the options that you want to disable.**

*Source for more details*  - [*Spellchecking with intelliJ*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/spellchecking.html)

Comment: actually, alt+enter then "correct *word*" then "disable" works fine too

Comment: (+1) I hate to see my code with those red line on the bottom. PD: Thanks.

Comment: Android Studio 1.0.2: File>>Settings>>Inspections>>Spelling>>Typo
but File>>Settings and search "spelling" is better! :)

Comment: Just to be clear, the options you can disable will be in the right-hand column after you click on "Typo". Checking the "Typo" checkbox disables them all.

Comment: Another important setting: File >> Settings >> Version Control >> Commit Dialog >> Spelling.

Comment: Using this answer, and selecting "Default IDE" profile in the top of the setting popup will store this setting globally (for all your projects). Then you will be happy.

Comment: Is there any way to disable spell check for specific language only?

Comment: For me (v2020.3.2 on macOS) this is under 
`Preferences => Editor => Inspections => Proofreading => *`
... uncheck Boxes as needed.

Comment: Updated response Spelling was changed to Proofreading

Comment: Quicker to just search for "Proofreading" in settings rather than navigating the tree.

Answer (score 24):

For 12.1.6 on OSX:

`Preferences->Inspections->Spelling`

Answer (score 22):

I've put together a "visual solution" here (inspired by a previous solution above/below by @user277236 in this forum!).

In Webstorm you can either:

1. Disable spell checking **entirely**, or
2. Disable spell checking **selectively** (e.g. just the code), but enable for some others (e.g. comments).

I'm on MacOS Webstorm (version 2016.1.2). First thing first, go to the "Inspection" pane like this...

```
Webstorm -> Preferences -> search for "Inspections"
```

or...

```
Webstorm -> Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections
```

Within the Inspection search box, search "Spelling".

## Option 1 - Disable spell-checking entirely

[image]

## Option 2 - Disable spell-checking selectively

[image]

I've gone for option 2 myself. This seems to work for me so far.

Comment: You might add how to disable for the current js file: `// noinspection SpellCheckingInspection` (see [supress-spellchecker](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/spellchecking.html#supress-spellchecker)), and `<!--suppress SpellCheckingInspection -->` for HTML (That was not exactly the question, but I laded here when searching).

Answer (score 13):

Use the annotation for the class / method / field

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
```

Answer (score 8):

In Windows and Android 2.3 ...

File -> Settings -> Inspections -> Spelling ...

[image]

Answer (score 5):

They need to introduce **@spellcheck:off** like the formatter.

Comment: There is an annotation for that ```@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")```

Answer (score 5):

update for 2020

```
File >> Settings >> Editor >> Inspections >> Proofreading (uncheck all)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For Android Studio, I found "Inspections" directly under "Project Settings," and not under "IDE Settings/Editor".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to suppress in a file, you can use comment in file 
like `<!--suppress SpellCheckingInspection -->` in html.

Answer (score 1):

On Android Studio version 1.1 on Mac setting off Spelling from File menu does not work.

Set spelling from Android Studio > Preferences > Inspections.

Uncheck Typo and uncheck Spelling located in the first group of options "Project Settings".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable it for all future project, you can disable it in the new project setting:

**File | New Projects Settings | Preferences for New Projects...**

source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010504879-Disable-spellcheck-everywhere-globally-

Answer (score 0):

In MS, you can use `Alt+Enter` to disable the inspections.

Answer (score 0):

I have just find out that the typo inspection feature is provided by the Grazie plugin, which comes pre-installed in IntelliJ. You can just disable displugin in the setting and all typo inspection feature will no longer be available.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBXxI.jpg)